# problem with 13.04 migration to 13.10

Tags: boot, filesystem

System hung while attempting to update from 13.04 to 13.10. When I attempt to reboot I receive the following message:

```
# Filesystem check or mount failure.
# A maintenance shell will now be started.
# CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and continue booting after re-trying
filesystem. Any further errors will be ignored.

# Give root password for maintenance (or type Control-d to continue:
```

**Note:** Nothing happens when I try to type my password. It just hangs.

Prior to this I was using 13.04 without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a month, but I managed to fix it:

1. boot with a liveCD.
2. open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>).
3. type `sudo fdisk -l` (lowercase <kbd>L</kbd>, not <kbd>1</kbd>) and check where you have mounted your linux partition (mine is /dev/sda1; if yours is different, just replace it below).
4. enter the following series of commands:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /mnt/my_linux
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/my_linux
   sudo mount -t proc proc /mnt/my_linux/proc
   sudo mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/my_linux/sys
   sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/my_linux/dev
   sudo chroot /mnt/my_linux/ /bin/bash
   ```

   (this mount your hard drive to make system changes, and changes the root environment in where you are working to be the hard drive instead of the livecd.)
5. then type:

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /
   dpkg --configure -a
   ```

   (this should fix the problem.)
6. when the preceding command completes, type `exit` and `sudo reboot`

That's all. If this works, backup all your files and re-install if need be so that your system is in a good state.